# javascript function within the function

Tags: javascript, reflection, scope

So I was wondering if it is possible to access a variable (which has a value of function) from outside the scope. I have code that goes something like this:

```
function parentFunction(){
  var childFunction = function() {
    // do something
  }
}

$(function(){
  // need to access childFunction() here.
});
```

Comment: Can `parentFunction()` return the `childFunction()` variable at the end of it's execution? Or are you trying to affect the `childFunction()` before calling `parentFunction()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var childFunction;

function parentFunction(){
  childFunction = function() {
    // do something
  }
}

$(function(){
  childFunction();
});
```

Comment: I suppose if childFunction captures any closures in parentFunction this is useful, but otherwise you lose namespacing and pollute the global namespace.

Comment: assuming that this is happening globally all together, I'm simply illustrating scope...

Comment: It worked - I just had to call the parentFunction first to initialize the value of childFunction. Then I was able to call the childFunction. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not.  The only way to achieve this is to make the desired childFunction an attribute of parentFunction:

```
var parentFunction = (function(){
  var actualParentFunction = function(){
      this.childFunction = function() {
        // do something
      };
  }

  return new actualParentFunction();
})();
```

At which point you can do:

```
parentFunction.childFunction();
```